# How to DIY terminate 62.5 µm Multimode Fiber (MMF)?

Tags: networking, fiber

I wired my house using a Honeywell Genesis series multimedia cable (part no. [5956](https://www.honeywellcable.com/CatalogDocuments/5956.pdf)). Among four other cables, it also has (2) 62.5um multimode fibers bundled together in a cable. (Those two 62.5/125 MMF are surrounded by Kevlar under PVC jacket.)

Following is the optical characteristic of the fiber optic cable:

```
Core/Clad | Typ. Atten. | Max Atten. | Min LED Bandwidth
          |  (dB/km)    |  (dB/km)   |     (Mhz*km)
-------------------------------------------------------- 
62.5/125  |  3.0 / 1.0  | 3.75 / 1.5 |    160 / 500
```

From previously posting [this question on the Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42863/how-to-diy-terminate-multimode-fiber) StackExchange, it appears it's rather antiquated “FDDI grade” fiber. (My question being home-related was flagged off-topic there though, hence posting this here.) But, because it is installed in a medium size house, runs are no more than 50ft, most of them less and so I'm hoping to be able to use it to do 10Gbe.

I am finishing the network wiring now, and I am able to terminate all RG6 and Ethernet connections in my Keystone wall plates for the other four cables, but I don't know what I need in order to terminate that fiber optic cable in a keystone wall plate.

Any guidance or DIY tutorial available for that?

Note: This question [How to DIY terminate Multimode Fiber?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42863/how-to-diy-terminate-multimode-fiber) was previously asked on NetworkEngineering exchange but closed as off-topic. (Since it is a DIY question.)

Comment: That depends on the quality of the connection you want/need and how the wall plate works. Why not link your original question it might have some more information already? Depending on the kind of connection you want you might need to spend a lot money or just some money. You probably will need to get a flat surface on either end (as flat as possible) which you either acquire by manual working (which is never going to be perfect) or having a device that does it for you (which is expensive). Did you consider hiring a company?

Comment: According to what I remember from my last year's youtube binge, you'd need 1) a fiber cleaver/scoring tool; 2) a pre-made OM1 fiber "pigtail" with connector of your choice; 3) a "mechanical splice" for connecting the former to the fiber; 4) lots of luck if you want to run 10G through it.

Comment: This is already answered where you first asked it, including your options for terminating it. I suppose I could copy and paste the answer here, but it does not change anything.